# Cannot load Rampart module within Axis2 client project

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

While my project is a Java web application, I use web services only as client.

I successfully created stubs with Apache Axis2 and tested them with SoapUI. Now it's time to implement security. [This is](https://edwin.eurodw.eu/edservices/2.2/PerformanceDataUploadService.svc?wsdl) one of the services I must integrate. It ships a WS-Security policy so that I must trasmit my credentials properly.

I want to integrate Apache Rampart into my project. I have found lots of difficulties downloading the required JARs and MAR file to use, but I made it.

Now I have the following project structure:

```
webapp
   -- WEB-INF
       -- classes
       -- conf
          -- axis2.xml
       -- modules
          -- several -mar files
          -- rampart-1.6.2.mar
          -- modules.list
       -- spring
          -- various context files
       -- web.xml
```

I use Spring to initialize all beans, including web service stubs. If I let Spring instantiate them normally, they work as expected. But when I use a `BeanPostProcessor` to engage the rampart module it will fail

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to engage module : rampart
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.engageModule(ServiceClient.java:363)
at it.csttech.edwin.security.SecurityHandler.engage(SecurityHandler.java:52)
```

In my axis2.xml I have added `<module ref="rampart" />` after `addressing`

I enable Rampart with the following code:

```
    RampartConfig rc = new RampartConfig();
    rc.setUser(user);
    Policy policy = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(new StAXOMBuilder(policyStream).getDocumentElement()); //XML policy file in classpath
    policy.addAssertion(rc);
    serviceClient.engageModule("rampart"); //this fails
    Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();
    options.setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, callbackHandler); //This will provide password
    options.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY, policy); //This will provide policy
```

I discovered that if I do `Map<String, AxisModule> modules = serviceClient.getAxisConfiguration().getModules();` I just get an empty map!!!!

So no modules are loaded at all.

Then I tried to move the modules/ directory to another place on my hard drive, and link it via system property `axis2.repo` but even if Axis2 won't load if I willignly set a bad path, it just won't load the `rampart-1.6.2.mar` file and the map will be still empty.

I'm getting crazy. I don't know how to properly load Rampart into my setup. I don't even know if Spring IoC can be used to inject a proper configuration and/or engage Rampart in all services.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating ConfigurationContext and use it get ServiceClient.

```
// create configuration context
ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(RESOURCES_DIR, null);

// create service client
ServiceClient serClient = new ServiceClient(ctx, null);

// engage modules
serClient.engageModule("rampart");
```

Where 'RESOURCES_DIR' should point to the location of your .mar files.

Comment: Same error. I triple-checked that System.getProperty("axis2.repo") is valued to the correct directogy, i.e. "C:/path/to/modules/"

Comment: RESOURCES_DIR ("axis2.repo") should point to parent of modules directory and this parent directory should also include services directory. Take a look at https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/adv-userguide.html (search for a chapter named "Axis2 Repository" where repository structure is explained)